# DevExpress Aspxcallbackpanel Client Side Timeout?

Tags: ajax, devexpress

I've read plenty about how to handle Server-Side timeouts & errors during a Callback...
but what about Client Side timeouts?

here's the example.
Guy fills out a web form. Hits submit & the ASPXCallbackPanel does a PerformCallback.
But right then... his internet drops or his router burps.

In my app, the Callback panel never returns control back to the Webpage.. and the callback never completes.
Anybody know a Timeout settings on the Client side? or a way to abort a callback through Javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would start a timer everytime a callback is sent to the server and refresh the page when the timer ticks.  If the callback returns earlier, the timer should be stopped.  This can be easily done using the [ASPxGlobalEvents](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGlobalEventsASPxGlobalEventstopic) control.